# Quick check on increment/decrement operators in C++

Tags: c++, increment, variable-declaration, decrement

Two examples of variable declarations are listed:

Example 1:

```
x = 10;
y = ++x;
```

Example 2:

```
x = 10;
y = x++;
```

The book said that in Example 1 *y* equals 11, and in Example 2 *y* equals 10. I think I get why and here's my reasoning, so please let me know if I've got this and/or if there's a more concise way of thinking about it.

In the first example, *y* equals 11 because it's simply set to equal "x + 1" since the increment operator comes first, whereas in the second example *y* is set to be equal to the original declaration of *x* and then the increment operation occurs on *x* separately. It seems to make sense since visually in Example 2 the variables are both right next to the equals sign and then the "x + 1" operation would occur as an afterthought to that equation with no effect on *y*.

Comment: ++x increments x and returns the incremented number, x++ returns x and then increments it :P good luck!

Comment: Much easier way to put it than I described, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right.

```
y=++x
```

means:
   `x++;
    y=x;`

HOWEVER,

```
y=x++;
```

means:
    
`y=x;
x++;`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have got it but it can be understood in simpler words.

```
y = x++;
```

Increment x after this line. Result is

```
y = 10, x = 11
```

Whereas in

```
y = ++x;
```

Increment x before this line. Result is

```
y = 11, x = 11
```

Answer (score 1):

Golden rule:

Prefix increment/decrement (++x or --x) have right-to-left associativity.

Postfix increment/decrement (x++ or x--) have left-to-right associativity.

```
x = 10

if (x++ == 11) {        
    // Post increment
}


if (++x == 11 ) {
    // Pre increment
}
```

So in you case:

Example 1:

```
x = 10;
y = ++x;
```

Original value of x (here 10) is incremented first and then assigned to y.

Example 2:

```
x = 10;
y = x++;
```

Original value of x is first assigned to y and then incremented (to 11).